# Wordpress page template: Exactly the same as original template, but body of page template is gone

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I have a wordpress page in which I want to change some things. The page uses the enfold template with the following page.php:

```
<?php
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') ){ die(); }

global $avia_config;

/*
 * get_header is a basic wordpress function, used to retrieve the header.php file in your theme directory.
 */
 get_header();


 if( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'header', true) != 'no') echo avia_title();

 do_action( 'ava_after_main_title' );
 ?>

    <div class='container_wrap container_wrap_first main_color <?php avia_layout_class( 'main' ); ?>'>

        <div class='container'>

            <main class='template-page content  <?php avia_layout_class( 'content' ); ?> units' <?php avia_markup_helper(array('context' => 'content','post_type'=>'page'));?>>

                <?php
                /* Run the loop to output the posts.
                * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
                * called loop-page.php and that will be used instead.
                */

                $avia_config['size'] = avia_layout_class( 'main' , false) == 'fullsize' ? 'entry_without_sidebar' : 'entry_with_sidebar';
                get_template_part( 'includes/loop', 'page' );
                ?>

            <!--end content-->
            </main>

            <?php

            //get the sidebar
            $avia_config['currently_viewing'] = 'page';
            get_sidebar();

            ?>

        </div><!--end container-->

    </div><!-- close default .container_wrap element -->
```

And this is my page-myslug.php:

```
<?php
/*
 * Template Name: Backer lightbox
 */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') ){ die(); }

global $avia_config;

/*
 * get_header is a basic wordpress function, used to retrieve the header.php file in your theme directory.
 */
 get_header();


 if( get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'header', true) != 'no') echo avia_title();

 do_action( 'ava_after_main_title' );
 ?>

    <div class='container_wrap container_wrap_first main_color <?php avia_layout_class( 'main' ); ?>'>

        <div class='container'>

            <main class='template-page content  <?php avia_layout_class( 'content' ); ?> units' <?php avia_markup_helper(array('context' => 'content','post_type'=>'page'));?>>

                <?php
                /* Run the loop to output the posts.
                * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
                * called loop-page.php and that will be used instead.
                */

                $avia_config['size'] = avia_layout_class( 'main' , false) == 'fullsize' ? 'entry_without_sidebar' : 'entry_with_sidebar';
                get_template_part( 'includes/loop', 'page' );
                ?>

            <!--end content-->
            </main>

            <?php

            //get the sidebar
            $avia_config['currently_viewing'] = 'page';
            get_sidebar();

            ?>

        </div><!--end container-->

    </div><!-- close default .container_wrap element -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

However, when I load the page that has its' page template set to this page template, it displays only the header and the footer; Not the body that the original page has.

How can I duplicate the entire first page using a page template?

Comment: Is your new page template in the same directory as page.php?

Comment: It is. After some further investigation though, I suspect the problem might lie within the Avia Layout Builder that my client is apparantly using...